# Tag with Alias capability

Tags: tags

Is there such a feature in WordPress, that you have one tag which is the alias for another?

Example:

Muhammad Ali and Cassius Clay is the same thing. I have two separate tags for each. 
And I tag my article only with "Muhammad Ali", while another colleague of mine could tag  another article which talks about the same boxer as "Cassius Clay". And we want our visitors to be able to click on either term (that is "Cassius Clay" or "Muhammad Ali") and end up on the same URL.

Now, where does this come handy you may ask...

When I display my tag cloud alphabetically, wouldn't it be nice for the visitors to be able to go to either C's or M's and spot the topic regardless?.
So, when you go to the C's, and click on "Cassius Clay" in there, you end up on the same URL as those who scan the M's and click on "Muhammad Ali".

I guess the functionality I need here is the same as that is found at the back of many books. You go look up a term (ex: Cassius Clay) at the index, and you read something like "see Muhammad Ali" eventually getting you to the correct page.

If WordPress does not have a solution for this, my back up plan is to analyze the terms using the [Google trend tool](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Muhammad%20ali,%20Cassius%20clay) and pick the one which has the better volume and go with that as the first term and postfix the other term into parenthesis, i.e, *"Muhammad Ali (Cassius Clay)"*.

This unfortunately won't help those users who seek the topic under the wrong alphabetical heading.

I'd like to hear your opinions on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it via the admin UI, but there is an `alias_of` argument for [`wp_insert_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) which accepts a slug for the term you want it to be an alias of. In practice, I don't know exactly how this works. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/wp-hackers/2Phxyj7Mzwo) from wp-hackers.

Comment: thank you for your answer Milo. I'd like to hear more opinions/solutions about this. So before I can select your answer as the one, I'd like to wait a little more. I also asked the same q on hackers list. I will share any input in this regard if anything comes up.